# Find norm of the integral operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Find norm of the following bounded linear operator 
$$Ax(t)=\int_0^1e^{-ts}x(s)ds$$ where $x\in C[0,1]$ and $t\in[0,1]$. Please help  me.

Comment: i tried but i can't find $\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}$.

Comment: this maybe because it is $\infty$ if you take $t$ to $0$. if you write out what you have tried, you will almost certainly get more attention/more help.

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts on $\int_0^1 x(s) {1 \over s}(1 - e^{-s}) ds$?

Comment: I tried to prove that $||A||=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int\limits_0^1e^{-ts}ds=\sup\limits_{t\in [0,1]}\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}$. But I can't find supremum. I guess that supremum equals 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$
\Vert A(x)\Vert
=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\left|\int_0^1 e^{-ts}x(s)ds\right|
\leq\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 |e^{-ts}||x(s)|ds
\leq\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 1\cdot\sup\limits_{s\in[0,1]}|x(s)|ds
\\=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 \Vert x\Vert ds
=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\Vert x\Vert
=\Vert x\Vert
$$
Hence $\Vert A\Vert\leq 1$. Consider constant function $x_0=1$, then $\Vert x_0\Vert=1$ and
$$
\Vert A(x_0)\Vert=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int\limits_0^1 e^{-ts}ds=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}\geq\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1-e^{-n^{-1}}}{n^{-1}}\geq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n(1-e^{-n^{-1}})=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n(1-(1-n^{-1}))=1
$$
Thus for $x_0$ with $\Vert x_0\Vert=1$ we get $\Vert A(x_0)\Vert\geq 1$. Hence $\Vert A\Vert\geq 1$, but as we showed later $\Vert A\Vert\leq 1$. Therefore $\Vert A\Vert=1$.