# Show that the operator $(Ax)(t)= \int_{0}^{t} e^{-s}x(s) ds$ is bounded and find its norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

The question is as follows:

Prove that the operator $A : L_p[0,1] \to L_q[0,1]$

$$(Ax)(t)= \int_{0}^{t} e^{-s}x(s) ds$$
is indeed bounded and calculate its norm.

$\textbf{some attempt}:$

For to show its boundedness we have $||Ax||_{L_q}^{q} = \int_{0}^{1} \mid \int_{0}^{t} e^{-s} x(s) ds \mid^q dt$

$\hspace{8.2cm} \leq \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{t} \mid e^{-s} x(s) \mid^q ds dt  $

$\hspace{8.2cm} \leq \int_{0}^{1} ((\int_{0}^{t} \mid e^{-s} \mid^q ds ) (\int_{0}^{t} \mid x(s) \mid^{p} ds)^{\frac{q}{p}} ) dt$

$\hspace{8.2cm} = \int_{0}^{1} (\int_{0}^{t} \mid e^{-s} \mid^q ds) ||x||_{L_p}^{q} dt$

$\hspace{8.2cm} = ||x||_{L_p}^{q} \int_{0}^{1}  \int_{0}^{t}  e^{-sq} ds dt$

$\hspace{8.2cm} = ||x||_{L_p}^{q} \int_{0}^{1} (-\frac{e^{-sq}}{q})\mid_{0}^{t} dt $

$\hspace{8.2cm} =  ||x||_{L_p}^{q}  \int_{0}^{1} (-\frac{e^{-tq}}{q} + \frac{1}{q}) dt$

$\hspace{8.2cm} = ||x||_{L_p}^{q} (\frac{e^{-tq}}{q^2} + \frac{t}{q})\mid_{0}^{1}$

$\hspace{8.2cm} = ||x||_{L_p}^{q} (\frac{e^{-q^2}}{q^2}+ \frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{q^2})$

So we have that $A$ is bounded and $||A||_{L_q}\leq (\frac{e^{-q^2}}{q^2}+ \frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{q^2})$.

But I do not know how to calculate its norm?

Can you please let me know how to find it?

And can you please let me know if there is anything wrong in my calculation?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use \begin {align} and \end {align} (without the spaces) with an & before each equals sign instead of using hspace on each line. Also, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362492/find-norm-of-the-integral-operator?rq=1) might help with your problem.

Comment: General strategy: Try to find the best bound on $\|Ax\|_q / \|x\|_p$ you can, and then when you have $\|Ax\|_q / \|x\|_p \leq ...$, try to  find a vector $x|$ for which equality holds in this formula. Then you know that the right hand side is the operator norm. Here, concretely, maybe the Hölder inequality might help, I'm unsure.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks! But that is a completely different story and easier. I wanna know if my calculation is correct?

Comment: Your calculation is correct and so is Luke's suggestion. The operator norm is 
$$\Vert A\Vert=\sup\{\Vert Ax\Vert_{L^q([0,1]}:\,\Vert x\Vert_{L^p([0,1]}=1\}.$$ You have shown that $$ ||A||\leq (\frac{e^{-q^2}}{q^2}+ \frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{q^2}).$$ Now you have to choose a good $x$ to get equality.

Comment: @Gio67 Many thanks! Can you please help me to find such a $x \in L_p[0,1]$?

Comment: Try the simplest $x$ you can think of.

Comment: @Gio67 Thanks! Maybe just $x(s) = \frac{e^{s-q^2}}{q^2} + \frac{e^s}{q} - \frac{e^s}{q^2}$? But then we will have problem with $t$!

Comment: @Gio67 Can you please let me know what is the simplest $x$ which can give me the norm? Thanks!

Comment: did you try $x=1$?

Comment: @Gio67 Thanks a lot! That really works!